# forever stop / forever start if (процесс существует - по имени)?

Tags: bash

Как можно правильно реализовать проверку на существование процесса forever по имени и выполнять ту или иную команду в зависимости от этого?

```
execute "cd #{release_path}/bem && forever stop #{application}; env PORT=#
```

```
{nodejs_port} NODE_STAGING=true YENV=production forever start --uid #{application} -a #{bem_server}"
```

> команда, которую я использую.

Comment: `if pgrep forever >/dev/null; then echo да; else echo нет; fi`

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста (и уж тем более не в виде картинки на каком-то хостинге): а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, + `-x`, а то `foreveryoung` тоже попадёт.

Comment: @0andriy, вот и напишите полноценный ответ.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, вы начали, вы лучше справитесь.